# Understanding an iOS stacktrace

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm kinda new to debugging iOS exceptions.

On the fabric.io site I can see that a few users has seen this crash. 
Can anyone please help me get started?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  gismoapp                      0x114760 specialized WeekPlanController.scrollViewWillBeginDragging(UIScrollView) -> () (WeekPlanController.swift:428)
1  gismoapp                      0x1144a0 specialized WeekPlanController.scrollViewWillBeginDragging(UIScrollView) -> () (WeekPlanController.swift:428)
2  gismoapp                      0x11102c @objc WeekPlanController.scrollViewWillBeginDragging(UIScrollView) -> () (WeekPlanController.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x261b4609 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewWillBeginDragging] + 232
4  UIKit                          0x261b3a9d -[UIScrollView _updatePanGesture] + 284
5  UIKit                          0x265685db _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 142
6  UIKit                          0x261a08e3 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 170
7  UIKit                          0x26030d15 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1004
8  UIKit                          0x2656993f ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898 + 62
9  UIKit                          0x25ff1587 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 298
10 UIKit                          0x25fedaf9 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2920
11 UIKit                          0x2602ec01 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 904
12 UIKit                          0x2602e3b3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 622
13 UIKit                          0x25ffec85 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
14 UIKit                          0x25ffd229 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5016
15 CoreFoundation                 0x219efa67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
16 CoreFoundation                 0x219ef657 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
17 CoreFoundation                 0x219ed9bf __CFRunLoopRun + 806
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2193c289 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2193c07d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
20 GraphicsServices               0x22f58af9 GSEventRunModal + 160
21 UIKit                          0x260672c5 UIApplicationMain + 144
22 gismoapp                      0xb7084 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x215e8873 (Missing)
```

The code in question:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView){

    if let lastSyncDate = Settings.lastSyncedDate {
        // This is line 428 in WeekPlanController
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "last synced \(lastSyncDate.relativeTimeToString()) ago") 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual exception message?

Comment: got nothing more in the fabric interface. Or maybe I just cant find it

Comment: What if try to set breakpoint for all exception? Maybe it gives more information?

Comment: The exception does not be provoked in development. The stacktrace is from fabric.io (from a real customers phone)